Gluing coordinate vector fields on a symplectic manifold
I wonder if there exists an open covering of a symplectic manifold for which the hypotheses for gluing coordinate vector fields are satisfied. In general, I don't think that coordinate vector fields restricted to charts intersections coincide, and thus can't be glued.
But does being on a symplectic manifold provide us with a way to choose such a cover?

The 2-sphere is symplectic. It doesn't have nonzero vector fields. Coordinate vector fields don't vanish. Is that a counterexample to what you had in mind?
